# Trying to identify scifi story involving aliens/telepathy/music talent

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, telepathy

I read a scifi story years ago. It may have been in one of the scifi magazines.

It involved Earth having established a relationship with an alien race that valued above all art in all its forms.

- They have technology that can both read and transmit thoughts.
- A music store owner buys a house that among other things can play music.
- While viewing the house he keeps noting the technical errors in the music which are each automatically corrected as he notices them.
- The fact that he was able to notice those things, however, tipped off the aliens that he was far more musically gifted than his life would imply.
- Examining his life further the aliens realized that this man's fingers weren't nimble enough to play any musical instruments Earth had to offer.
- They give him a different house, one without any telepathic illusions or broadcasts (because they have a firm rule about not tampering with the perceptions of artists) and also give him a cone shaped device that responds to his thoughts and produces any music he can imagine.
- He becomes a very famous music performer.

Answer (score 3):

It can be [Creative Constructions, Inc.](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?47799) by Kent Patterson

I searched Google Books for *house correct music subject:"science fiction"* and the [Analog Science Fiction and Fact](https://books.google.com/books?id=_LUjAQAAMAAJ) record was the fourth result:

> Hansell let the music flow through him. Bit dead on the upper register of the second violin - no. One of the kettle drums too tight - no. Incredible. The second he spotted the slightest flaw in the music, it seemed to correct itself. Pure magic. Marvelous acoustics!
>
> "I'll buy it! How much?"
>
> "Only $149,999.95, complete."